# python - No module named dill while using pickle.load()

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, dill

I have dill installed in my python 2.7 but when I try to unpickle my model it says "No module named dill". The pickled file contains pandas series.

EDIT :
Here's the snapshot of the traceback on ElasticBeanstalk environment

```
File "/opt/python/current/app/app/models/classification.py", line 663, in __init__
  self.lookupdict = pickle.load(open(<filepath>))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
  return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
  klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
  __import__(module)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
  result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named dill
```

Comment: What happens if you do a simple `import dill`?

Comment: Sometimes its the small things that hold up a program

Comment: Actually, it works on my local machine and even on the virtual environment on ec2 but when i deploy it with ElasticBeanstalk it throws this error. I'll try by importing dill. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, Didn't work.

Comment: `Have you already installed dill (`pip install dill`) on your destination environment?

Comment: Yes, it's in the requirements. It's getting imported as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If version on your Elastic beanstalk or error environment is greater than your local version then downgrade your dill package to the package which is working on your EC2 or local machine.
On your local machine, check current dill package:

```
pip freeze | grep -i 'dill'
```

e.g it outputs: dill==0.2.7.1 which is lower than what it is on beanstalk

then downgrade using

```
pip install dill==0.2.7.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) This looks like a $PATH issue (or, similarly, a linking issue)... You seem to have at least two python installations (one at /opt/python, presumably from something like macports, and one at /usr/lib64, and possibly a third in a venv).

I'm guessing that if you carefully confirm which python you are using, and which corresponds to the `pip` you used, you might find `dill` and the other modules you are using are not all in the same python installation.

2) Note that in the first line of the traceback you seem to be using `pickle.load`... if you want to use `dill`, shouldn't you be using `dill.load` to unpickle the serialized object?